# Web stats direct entry informatiom

Tags: web, matomo

I was testing the Piwik web statistics application. What is supprise to me is that this app can tell if the entry to the certian page is a "direct entry" or entry from some other website.

How does it work? How does the Piwki app obtains this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, it looks at the [Referer HTTP header](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/blob/d54ddc8b9f4d19bb8b4c69dd02776e3766211261/core/Tracker/Request.php#L77).

More specifically, the Javascript tracker sends two parameters: `url` and `urlref`. The `url` is always the current page, and `urlref` will be the previous page if there was a previous page. `urlref` might be an external page (hence Piwik's knowledge of search referrers and other sites), or it might be another page on the same site (which I assume Piwik uses for its pathing information).